# SQLite showing retrieved data perfectly on emulator, but doesn't retrieve anything on actual device/in app

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

This has brought a lot of confusion to me.

So everything is working 100% perfectly on emulator, but when I test it on actual phone, no data is being retrieved, unless I create some from the phone, and retrieve it. My app is designed such that promoter uploads data, and data is being displayed to consumers. For testing I'm uploading dummy data.

I did went on and published the app, and after downloading there's no promoter data being shown, MEAN WHILE, SQLite database has promoter data in it!!!. The only data that is being shown in app is the one I create through app. I asked my friend to download the app to test it, and same results came, no data being shown.

**Code for uploading Data**

```
 Boolean insertData = myDb.insertData(product, restaurant, promotion, location, spinnerText); 
                if (insertData = true) { 
                    Toast.makeText(PromoteProductPage.this, "Saved!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShopPage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(PromoteProductPage.this, "Data Not Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

**My DatabaseHelper class**

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + tableName + " ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ProductName TEXT, RestaurantName TEXT, Promotion TEXT, Location TEXT, Category TEXT)");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName);
        onCreate(db);
    }

public boolean insertData(String product, String restaurant, String promotion, String location, String category){ 
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(COL_2, product);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, restaurant);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, promotion);
        contentValues.put(COL_5, location);
        contentValues.put(COL_6, category);
        long result = db.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);
        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**Retrieving Data**

Just for one class, every other class is structured same, just named accordingly.

```
 btBreakfast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor res = myDb.getBreakfastPlaces();
                if(res.getCount() == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(ShopPage.this, "No Product Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else {
                    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                    while (res.moveToNext()){ //movetonext moves cursor to next position
                        stringBuffer.append("Product: " + res.getString(1) + "\n"); 
                        stringBuffer.append("Restaurant: " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                        stringBuffer.append("Promotion: " + res.getString(3) + "\n");
                        stringBuffer.append("Location: " + res.getString(4) + "\n\n");
                    }
                    showData("BreakFast Places", stringBuffer.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

**Manifest**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

This is first time using SQLite database, I've looked into Execute SQL on DB Browser for SQLite, is there any kind of permission that I have not given for data to be displayed, I've looked into this problem for a week, no solution. If anyone has any experience/information regarding working of SQLite, YOUR HELP IS MUCH APPRECIATED. Thank You !.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
Cursor res = myDb.getBreakfastPlaces();
                if(res.getCount() == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(ShopPage.this, "No Product Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                } else {
                    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                    while (res.moveToNext()){ //movetonext moves cursor to next position
                        stringBuffer.append("Product: " + res.getString(1) + "\n"); 
                        stringBuffer.append("Restaurant: " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                        stringBuffer.append("Promotion: " + res.getString(3) + "\n");
                        stringBuffer.append("Location: " + res.getString(4) + "\n\n");
                    }
                    showData("BreakFast Places", stringBuffer.toString());
                }
```

with this:

```
Cursor res = myDb.getBreakfastPlaces();
            if(res.getCount() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(ShopPage.this, "No Product Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } else {
                if(res.moveToFirst()){
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                do{ //movetonext moves cursor to next position
                    stringBuffer.append("Product: " + res.getString(1) + "\n"); 
                    stringBuffer.append("Restaurant: " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                    stringBuffer.append("Promotion: " + res.getString(3) + "\n");
                    stringBuffer.append("Location: " + res.getString(4) + "\n\n");
                }while (res.moveToNext());
                }
                showData("BreakFast Places", stringBuffer.toString());
            }
```